# Trying to create two bootstrap template coloumn

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create simple template with two coloumns. Here is what i got so far

[image]

I'm using bootstrap. Now i want to ask . Why my sidebar position is leaving some space?

The left side use this `<div class="pull-left col-sm-7"></div>` and my right side `<div class="col-sm-5">`

Here is my html Code

```
<div class="container">

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"><img class="headerimg" src=""></div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"> 
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:84/jdih/">Home</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7"> 
<img src="" class="img-responsive" style='float:left;width:200px;height:200px; margin-right:10px;'>
<p class="text-justify">Text <br>
Text
</p>
<p class="text-justify">
Text</p>
<p class="text-justify">
Text
</p>

<p class="text-justify">Text</p>

<p class="text-justify">Text<br>
Text<br>
Text</p>

<p class="text-justify">Text</p>

<p class="text-justify"><strong>Text</strong>.</p>
</div>


<div class="col-md-5 pull-right"> 
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="col-md-5">
                           <label>Jenis</label>

                            <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                            <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>

                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-5">

                           <label>Kategori</label>
                                                        <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                            <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>

                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group"> 
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                           <label>Tahun</label>

                            <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                            <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>

                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label>Cari Berdasarkan</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                                         <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label>Kata Kunci</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-5">

                                    <input type="submit" class="btn pull-right btn-submit" value="Find">
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</div>
```

And here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/hv4c9yhd/.

So can you tell me how to make the `sidebar part` fill the empty space? Thanks in advance

Comment: empty space in both sides?

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
<div class="container-fluid">
```

instead of

```
<div class="container">
```

remove content out of container

or can remove container margin and padding with css

Answer (score 0):

Change `col-md-7`and `col-md-5` to `col-xs-7` `col-xs-5`. This will surely help. your screen might be extra small.

Comment: it's perfect when i zoom my chrome 150%

Comment: add `col-md-5`, `col-sm-5`, `col-xs-5` and then try, it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.headerimg{
    width : 100%;
   }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<div class="container">

     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12"><img class="headerimg" src=""></div>
   </div>
     <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12"> 
         <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:84/jdih/">Home</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 
             <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7 " style="display:inline-block;"> 
<img src="" class="img-responsive" style='float:left;width:200px;height:200px; margin-right:10px;'>
<p class="text-justify">Text <br>
Text
</p>
<p class="text-justify">
Text</p>
<p class="text-justify">
Text
</p>

<p class="text-justify">Text</p>

<p class="text-justify">Text<br>
Text<br>
Text</p>

<p class="text-justify">Text</p>

<p class="text-justify"><strong>Text</strong>.</p>
</div>


<div class="col-md-5 pull-right"> 
 <form class="form-horizontal">
     <div class="form-group"> 
         <div class="col-md-5">
                           <label>Jenis</label>
                           
                            <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                            <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>
                             
       </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                        <div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-5">

                           <label>Kategori</label>
                                                        <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                            <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>
                             
       </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                          <div class="form-group"> 
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                           <label>Tahun</label>
                           
                            <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                            <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>
                             
       </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                             <label>Cari Berdasarkan</label>
                              <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                                <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>
                                 </select>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                             <label>Kata Kunci</label>
                              <input type="text" class="form-control">
                      </div>
                  </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                             
                              <input type="submit" class="btn pull-right btn-submit" value="Find">
                      </div>
                  </div>
    </form>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `container` for `navbar`, if you don't want to give spaces in both sides. You can use `container` below of this `navbar` (as you want this)

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
   <div class="row">

     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"><img class="headerimg" src=""></div>
    </div>
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"> 
            <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost:84/jdih/">Home</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 
                    <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</div>
</div>
</div>


<div class="container">
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12"> 
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-7"> 
<img src="" class="img-responsive" style='float:left;width:200px;height:200px; margin-right:10px;'>
<p class="text-justify">Text <br>
Text
</p>
<p class="text-justify">
Text</p>
<p class="text-justify">
Text
</p>

<p class="text-justify">Text</p>

<p class="text-justify">Text<br>
Text<br>
Text</p>

<p class="text-justify">Text</p>

<p class="text-justify"><strong>Text</strong>.</p>
</div>


<div class="col-md-5 pull-right"> 
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <div class="col-md-5">
                           <label>Jenis</label>

                            <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                            <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>

                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group"><div class="col-md-5">

                           <label>Kategori</label>
                                                        <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                            <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>

                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group"> 
                          <div class="col-md-5">
                           <label>Tahun</label>

                            <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                            <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>

                            </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label>Cari Berdasarkan</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
                                         <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-5">
                                <label>Kata Kunci</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-5">

                                    <input type="submit" class="btn pull-right btn-submit" value="Find">
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </form>
</div>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I went through your code and found that you over use divs when defining a new class that can easily be appended to the previous parent div like this:

Instead of:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-md-5">
```

Doing this makes your code hard for others to understand and is bad practice. You can easily fix this by doing the following:

```
<div class ="form-group col-md-5">
```

It is essential that you understand this syntax, especially when working on your code or trying to comprehend another persons code. Basically this applies both the class .form-group and the class .col-md-5 to this div element. It is succinct and makes your code look a lot cleaner and easier to understand.

I cleaned up your code and adjusted some things. Let me know if this helps or if you need me to explain a specific section that I changed/deleted.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12"> 
      <img class="headerimg img-responsive" src="pic1 image">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
                <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Home</a>
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
     </div>

<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a></li>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>
    </div>`
</div>

<div class="col-md-4"> 
    <img src="" class="img-responsive" alt="picture2">
    <p class="text-justify">Text <br>Text</p>
    <p class="text-justify">Text</p>
    <p class="text-justify">Text</p>
    <p class="text-justify">Text</p>
    <p class="text-justify">Text<br>Text<br>Text</p>
    <p class="text-justify">Text</p>
    <p class="text-justify"><strong>Text</strong>.</p>
</div>


<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 pull-right"> 
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group col-md-5"> 
          <label>Jenis</label>
          <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
              <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>
          </select>
          </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
          <label>Kategori</label>
          <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
              <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
          <label>Tahun</label>
          <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
              <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
          <label>Cari Berdasarkan</label>
          <select class="form-control select2" name="parent">
              <option value="">Semua Jenis</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
          <label>Kata Kunci</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" place-holder="value">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-5">
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Find">
      </div>
  </form>
</div>`
```

The following code answers your question directly though:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
...</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 pull-right">
...</div>
```

There are many ways to make your form responsive as some of the other responses include. I just thought I would stress the importance of organization and appropriate use of divs and making sure every tag has it's appropriate closing tag.

Answer (score -1):

add this class "row-no-padding" to a parent div of your "col-sm-7" and "col-sm-5"-divs and then this css:

```
.row-no-padding > [class*="col-"] {
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer sorry! I meant a parent div should have this new class: https://jsfiddle.net/442kz4nf/